# Unity change output AudioMixerGroup

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change AudioSources volume and I want to achieve it by changing AudioMixerGroup.

I am trying to change AudioSources's AudioMixerGroup to a new one via script and I am loading it the following way:

```
audioSource.outputAudioMixerGroup = Resources.Load("Resources/AudioMixerWithSound") ; //Here it can convert an object to explicit AudioMixerGroup.
//audioSource.AudioMixerGroup = Resources.Load("AudioMixer/AudioMixerGroup") as AudioMixerGroup; // Here AudioMixerGroup doesn't exist.
```

So how can I change the AudioSOurce's outputAudioMixeGroup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is really no Unity Asset named `AudioMixerGroup`. Notice that the only audio mixing asset you can create is `AudioMixer` if you go to *Assets* --> *Create* --> *AudioMixer*. If this is how you created the mixer then the resources file type to load is `AudioMixer` not `AudioMixerGroup` and the extension should be *".mixer"*.

Note that you don't include the resources folder name in the `Resources.Load` function. If the *"AudioMixerWithSound"* file to load is the Resources folder, you would use `Resources.Load("AudioMixerWithSound")` to load it instead of `Resources.Load("Resources/AudioMixerWithSound")`. Also, the extension *".mixer"* is not included.

**Loading  the `AudioMixer` file from the Resources folder:**

```
//Get the AudioSource
AudioSource audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

//Load AudioMixer
AudioMixer audioMixer = Resources.Load<AudioMixer>("AudioMixerWithSound");

//Find AudioMixerGroup you want to load
AudioMixerGroup[] audioMixGroup = audioMixer.FindMatchingGroups("Master");

//Assign the AudioMixerGroup to AudioSource (Use first index)
audioSource.outputAudioMixerGroup = audioMixGroup[0];
```

Note that where the `AudioMixerGroup` is found with `FindMatchingGroups("Master")`, if it is a child object, you can use `/` to access the child like you would with the `GameObject.Find` function. For example, `FindMatchingGroups("Master/child")`. See the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Audio.AudioMixer.FindMatchingGroups.html) for more info.

Comment: applied this and it doesn't show any error but got the following error while executing :- NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
MicrophoneInput.changeAudioMixer () (at Assets/Scripts/MicrophoneInput.cs:116)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:166)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () .................................... line at  116 :- AudioMixerGroup[] audioMixGroup = audioMixer.FindMatchingGroups("Master");
..... I have two audioMixer.

Comment: Put `Debug.Log(audioMixer`)` under `AudioMixer audioMixer = Resources.Load<AudioMixer>("AudioMixerWithSound");` and tell me if it shows `null` in the Console tab.

Comment: Yes it is null. I have the 'AudioMixerWithSound' object in 'Resources' folder.

Comment: Select it in the Editor then post a screenshot for the whole Editor. Make sure it is selected.

Comment: I added the screenshot with the object selected.

Comment: I feel like you didn't read my answer but went directly to the code section. If I feel it's not necessary writing those, I wouldn't write them. It is `Resources.Load<AudioMixer>("AudioMixerWithSound")` not `Resources.Load<AudioMixer>("Resources/AudioMixerWithSound")`. I think you should copy the code directly

Comment: I have added a new screenshot and here I have assigned AudioMixer from editor and everything is working fine but I got the following error: UnassignedReferenceException: The variable audioMixer of MicrophoneInput has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the audioMixer variable of the MicrophoneInput script in the inspector.
MicrophoneInput.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/MicrophoneInput.cs:56)
 ........ Is it a bug?

Comment: When you get an error in Unity, **double click** on that error from the Console tab then post the code on that line of code. You can then create new question with that since I believe this like likely has nothing do with my answer. You want to post the complete code in that new question then show which line is causing that error. I'm sure many can help you.